# Из-за чего на десктопе кнопка есть, а на мобилке не отображается?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Сайт: https://geo-food.com/

В корзине есть кнопка "Продолжить покупки"[image: Скриншот корзины]

Кнопку добавляла через скрипт

```
 <script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.t706__sidebar-bottom').prepend("<button class='continue-btn'>ПРОДОЛЖИТЬ ПОКУПКИ</button>");
  $('.continue-btn').on('click touchend', function(){
    $('.t706__sidebar').removeClass('t706__sidebar_showed');
  });
});
</script>
```

В итоге на компе все работает, а на мобилке кнопки нет.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Необходим [минимально воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: У вас на мобильной и пк версии показываются разные блоки при нажатии на корзину. На мобилке показывается вот этот блок с классом `t706__cartpage`, а не `t706__sidebar`.

Comment: когда на мобилке в меню страницы выбираешь "показать полную версию", тогда кнопка есть

Comment: Поменяла класс, кнопка не появилась(

Comment: <script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.t706__cartpage-bottom').prepend("<button class='continue-btn'>ПРОДОЛЖИТЬ ПОКУПКИ</button>");
  $('.continue-btn').on('click touchend', function(){
    $('.t706__cartpage').removeClass('t706__cartpage_showed');
  });
});
</script>